# Function password_verify is slow when run under Valgrind

Tags: php, passwords, valgrind, php-extension, verify

I have created a PHP extension, it uses the password_verify. I have used the Valgrind for checking the memory leak. When I run the function password_verify, it takes 35 seconds for the response. Other functions work well. If I run the function without the Valgrind, it response really quick.

Comment: Possibly password_verify uses cryptographic instructions (such as AES extensions), and these instructions are emulated by valgrind using C code. This might be significantly slower than the usual slowdown of valgrind. If really critical, you might use valgrind debug tracing and profiling command options to further investigate to see if there are ways to make this faster

Comment: What exactly is the speed difference? I would expect a CPU-bound application to be 50-100x slower and an i/o bound applicatrion to be 10-20x slower, both with memcheck. You didn't provide the Valgrind options that you are using. One mistake that a lot of users make is that they see Valgrind has a lot of options and then they turn a load of them on. I advise against this. Run Valgrind with the minimum options necessary and afterwards if it detects errors consider turning on more options to get more details. Several of the options can cause a significant slowdown.

Comment: Hi @PaulFloyd Yep, I ran with minimum options ZEND_DONT_UNLOAD_MODULES=1 USE_ZEND_ALLOC=0 valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=no --track-origins=yes --log-file=output.txt /root/php-bin/DEBUG/bin/php -S localhost:8000 index.php

For the speed, as mentioned, it takes 35 seconds. For the /root/php-bin/DEBUG/bin/php -S localhost:8000 index.php, it will response immediately.

Comment: Don't use --track-origins=yes until you see errors like 'Used uninitialized'.

Comment: Hi @PaulFloyd, thank you for the suggestion, after remove the --track-origins=yes, it takes 16 seconds :)